# Typescript: assigning a memeber from an object

Tags: typescript

I am migrating an existing JS code to Typescript.

Suppose the existing JS code is like this:

```js
// Original JS class
class Test1 {
  constructor({ foo = 'a' }) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to define the class constructor using access modifier introduced in TypeScript as much as I could, so that I can assign a class member directly.

```js
// This will assign this.foo automatically.
// But the argument becomes different {foo} vs foo.
class Test2 {
  public constructor(private foo: string = 'a') {}
}
```

But the problem is now `Test2` have different parameter, which breaks existing code.

I cannot assign a member from an object parameter directly like this:

```js
// I want something like this... but error.
class Test3 {
  public constructor({ private foo: string = 'a' }) {}
}
```

So my goal is to avoid using `this.foo = foo` while preserving the parameter signature `constructor({foo})`. Is there a good workaround?

Comment: I believe that `private foo: string` will work fine. I do not understand your problem with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this is an open [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5326) with typescript, unfortunately you will have to do something like:

```
class Test4 {
    private foo: string;
    public constructor({ foo = 'a' }) {
        this.foo = foo;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, the issue's been more than 4 years. At least I glad to see it's not only me thinking about this. Thanks!